# ROBLOX - attempt to index number with 'Value' (NumberValues)

Tags: lua, roblox

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local LVL = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    LVL.Name = "LVL"
    LVL.Value = 1
    
    local XP = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    XP.Name = "XP"
    XP.Value = 0
    
    local requiredXP = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    requiredXP.Name = "RequiredXP"
    requiredXP.Value = LVL.Value * 100
    
    XP.Changed:Connect(function(Changed)
        if XP.Value >= requiredXP.Value then
            XP.Value = XP.Value - requiredXP.Value
            
            LVL.Value += 1
            requiredXP = LVL.Value * 100
        end
    end)
end)
```

On line 19,

```
    if XP.Value >= requiredXP.Value then
```

Why do I get this error: "**ServerScriptService.Script:19: attempt to index number with 'Value'**"

When I level up in the game, it crashes and I get this error. I don't know why